# The isomorphism of representive functions

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

$G$ is a compact Lie group with closed subgroup $H$ and $\mathscr{T}(G),\mathscr{T}(H)$ are the sets of their representative functions respectively (with real or complex representation). If the restriction map $i:\mathscr{T}(G) \rightarrow \mathscr{T}(H)$ is an isomorphism as algebra, then is $H=G$?

Comment: Could you explain what a "representative function" of $G$ means? Is this the set of finite-dimensional $G$-modules (over, say, reals) with the operations of addition and tensor multiplication?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_function